# CUDA deep copy with other data

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpu, cpu

I'm trying to copy my struct Test to the GPU, change the data, and upload it back to the CPU. This is what I've tried so far, note that my code crashes on the last, commented out, line:

```cpp
struct Test {
    int x, y;
    int* data;
};

// Test kernel
static __global__  void TestKernel(Test* d) {
    const uint32_t index = __mul24(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

    // increment some values
    ++d->data[0]; 
    ++d->data[1];
    ++d->data[2];

    ++d->x;
    ++d->y;
}

// Test snippet:
Test* host = new Test{ 10, 20,new int[3]{1, 2, 3} };
Test* device = nullptr;
int* deviceData;

COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMalloc(&device, sizeof(Test)));
COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMalloc(&deviceData, 3 * sizeof(int)));

COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(device, host, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(deviceData, host->data, 3 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(&(device->data), &deviceData, sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

TestKernel <<< 1, 1 >>> (device);
COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(host, device, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(host->data, deviceData, 3 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


printf("\nhost:\n");
printf("%d %d\n", host->x, host->y); // works
// printf("%d %d %d\n", host->data[0], host->data[1], host->data[2]); // crashes
```

Note that I've seen multiple related questions, but none of them also copy some data apart from the deep copied `data` pointer.

My error message:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7A2C5297D in VFD.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
> violation reading location 0x0000000B01600208.

Note that I'm probably copying the memory incorrectly, or something along those lines. If I remove the `COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(host, device, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));` line I'm able to access the `host->data` array, but the `x` and `y` values stay unincremented for obvious reasons.

Comment: You must build a copy of the device structure in host memory first, then copy it to the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `cudaMemcpy` into the host struct back from the GPU, you override the data pointer in it with an invalid GPU data pointer.

In order to fix it you need to restore the original data pointer (and then copy the actual data).

Working version:

```
struct Test 
{
    int x, y;
    int* data;
};


static __global__  void TestKernel(Test* d) 
{
    ++(d->data[0]);
    ++(d->data[1]);
    ++(d->data[2]);
    ++(d->x);
    ++(d->y);
}


int main() 
{
    int* hostData = new int[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };
    Test* host = new Test{ 10, 20, hostData };
    int* deviceData = nullptr;
    Test* device = nullptr;

    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMalloc(&device, sizeof(Test)));
    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMalloc(&deviceData, 3 * sizeof(int)));

    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(device, host, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(deviceData, host->data, 3 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(&(device->data), &deviceData, sizeof(int*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    TestKernel << < 1, 1 >> > (device);
    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(host, device, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    host->data = hostData;  // Restore host data pointer
    COMPUTE_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(host->data, deviceData, 3 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nhost:\n");
    printf("%d %d\n", host->x, host->y);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", host->data[0], host->data[1], host->data[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
host:
11 21
2 3 4
```

Some notes:

1. For clarity I added `()` in the kernel increment statements.
2. You used `sizeof(float*)` for the data pointer, although it is an `int*` (of course the size is the same).

Comment: By the way - is there a way of doing this without storing the intermediate buffers?

Comment: Are you referring to 'hostData' etc.?

Comment: correct, I'm guessing unified memory would do the trick, but I'm not sure :D

Comment: Not sure as well. I haven't used unified memory yet.

Comment: I see, guess I'll have a gander at UM and report my findings later. Thanks

Comment: Note that I've dabbled a bit with managed memory and it appears to do the trick, there are some issues here and there, but it does pretty much what I've wanted. My only question would be speed, but I'll see how fast/slow it is after I finish...